# Why does my elif go back to my if?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

I have written a very basic encryption program, and whilst writing the decrypting algorithm for it, I have encountered some problems with a loop I have.

```
from re import *

cipher = open('cipher.txt')
ciphertext = cipher.read()
keyfile = open('key.txt')
key = keyfile.read()
decoded = []
chardec = ''
inval = 1

print("Decoder for encrypt1.py")
while inval == 1:
    useManKey = input("Use a manual key? Y or N\n> ")
    if useManKey == 'Y' or 'y':
        key = input("Please enter the key you wish to use to decrypt\n> ")
        inval = 0
    elif useManKey == 'N' or 'n':
        inval = 0
        print("OK, decrypting")
    else:
        print("That wasn't a valid option/nPlease re-enter")
```

When I run this, and declare useManKey as N or n it seems to run the if part of the loop as if I had declared it as Y or y. I am probably being stupid here, but any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: When you use statement  useManKey == 'N' or 'n' left side 'N' or 'n' always return 'N'

Comment: maybe you could try `while True:` instead of `while inval == 1:`

Comment: @X.Jacobs He'd have to `break` out of the `while` then.  Though it would be arguably cleaner if the sentinel was a boolean, and the condition just said something like `while not valid_input_recieved:`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`useManKey == 'Y' or 'y'` does not work how you think it does.  What you want is `useManKey in ('Y', 'y')`.  What you have first evaluates `useManKey == 'Y'`, then, if that check fails, tests the string `'y'` for truishness.  Since non-empty strings are always truish, your `if` statement always evaluates to `True`.  As is pointed out in the comments, you could also use `upper()` or `lower()` to first convert the input to a fixed case if you want.

Comment: ...or `if useManKey.lower() == y`

Comment: @bgporter or just `upper/lower` the input to start with?

Comment: @Jon duh -- yeah, exactly. I need more coffee.

Comment: ...or `if useManKey in ['Y','y']`

Comment: @dedoco Not sure there is any appreciable difference between a list or a tuple in this case.  Or, for that matter, a set, `{'Y', 'y'}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
useManKey == 'Y' or 'y'
```

Doesn't actually check whether `useManKey` value being 'Y' or 'y', Use sr2222's answer for what you need to do. ie.

```
useManKey in ('Y', 'y')
```

The earlier expression evaluates to

```
(useManKey == 'Y') or 'y'
```

Which is always True irrespective of the value of `useManKey` as 'y' being non-Falsy (non-None) the 'or' of these always evaluates to True,